# Does Google Cloud support neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm a beginner of databases and I want to deploy neo4j on Google Cloud Platform.
I can find something about deploying MongoDB on Google, but nothing about neo4j.
So I wonder does Google Cloud support neo4j?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at this? http://www.neo4j.org/develop/cloud

Comment: Perhaps start with a hosted Neo4j service like Graphenedb.com and run your google apps application against that?

Comment: @MichaelHunger So that means still firebase doesn't support hosting neo4j database in the cloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neo4j is an open source project that could run your own Linux machine.

You could just create a Google Compute Engine instance, and follow the tutorials on the web to setup your Neo4j.

like this one: [Neo4j setup instruction](http://summerofphylet.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/neo4j-installation-guide/)

just follow the Linux part, and I suggest you to use Debian image to create your instance for Neo4j, because the command-line tool on Debian is most like to Ubuntu's one.

Comment: Answer has changed since the question was asked.  See below.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer from 2018.**

Yes -- neo4j supports Google Cloud.  Instructions can be found [on their website](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-cloud-deployment/).  You can use a pre-built image and launch a single node instance, or multi-node clusters on GCP.